# Python - Sending Emails Not Working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So i have a list of emails that i want to send a message to. When i run the code, i don't get any errors but the emails never go through/ here is the code (I already have all of the necessary imports)

```
def notifyUsers():
    users = session.query(Users).all()

    From = 'status@travellrs.com'
    Subject = "Travellr - Feedback"
    Contents = '''
         If you are experiencing issues with Travellr, please email - ryanwaite28@gmail.com

    Thank You For Using Travellr!

    '''

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('domain:port')
        server.starttls()
        server.login('login', 'password')

        for u in users:
            print (u.email)
            message = """\
            From: %s
            To: %s
            Subject: %s

            %s
            """ % \
            (From, ", ".join([u.email]), Subject, Contents)

            server.sendmail(From, [u.email], message)

        server.quit()
        print ('Emails Sent.')

    except Exception:
        print ('Error...')
```

Comment: `server = smtplib.SMTP('domain:port')` is that the correct domain and port?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP : smtplib.SMTP() needs you to specify domain and port separately in arguments.
Also, `except Exception:` doesn't look as a good idea.

Comment: i put domain and port to hide the actual info

Comment: thanks, i will try that